# Do I have to call Validate() in a code-behind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following event handler in my code-behind file that fires whenever an HTML form is submitted to the server:

```
public void Validate_Form(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check that the page is loaded due to a postback:
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        // Check that the page passed validation:
        if (IsValid)
        {
           // perform some logic...
        }
     }
}
```

My question is do I need to explicitly call `Validate()` method right before my `if (IsValid)` directive? What would be the difference between the following:

```
if (IsValid)                      Validate();
{                                 if (IsValid)
    ...              vs.          {
}                                     ...
                                  }
```

And since I am not seeing any errors / warnings, does that mean that the two above are identical? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same output.So explain this with an example. (You should turn off javascript for testing)

Suppose you have a page as follows:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTest1"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTest1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1"  ID="btnValidate1" Text="Validate1" OnClick="Validate_Form" />

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTest2"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup2"  runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTest2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup2"  ID="btnValidate2"  Text="Validate2" OnClick="Validate_Form" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

If we use first method:

```
public void Validate_Form(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check that the page is loaded due to a postback:
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            // Check that the page passed validation:
            if (IsValid)
            {
                // perform some logic...
            }
        }
    }
```

Validation buttons work properly.

But if we use second method:

```
public void Validate_Form(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validate();
        // Check that the page is loaded due to a postback:
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            // Check that the page passed validation:
            if (IsValid)
            {
                // perform some logic...
            }
        }
    }
```

Then if fill `txtTest1` and click on `btnValidate1` `IsValid` return false! because `Validate()` checks all of validations.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, `Validate()` will validate every single `TextBox` in the form? And also, if I had a form with just several `input` elements and a single submit `button`, then calling `Validate()` would be redundant, right?

Comment: @Alex Yes it's true.

Comment: @Alex please up vote and accept this answer if this answer helps you, so people know this is the correct answer.